# Checkout specific Hadoop release with git

Tags: git, hadoop

I need to make some local modifications to the Hadoop 2.6.0 source and than create .patch file using git. I will than provide this .patch file to someone who has fresh Hadoop 2.6.0.

To achieve this i need to use git to checkout release 2.6.0. How to checkout a particular release of Hadoop? If i am doing git clone git://git.apache.org/hadoop.git than i am getting master and all my attempts to switch to release 2.6.0 failed.

Can someone explain me how to checkout Hadoop 2.6.0 with git?
Thanks

Comment: What's the failure you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Apache git repository for accessing hadoop source code. Github may not contain the latest branches git://git.apache.org/hadoop.git

First clone git repository.

```
git clone git clone git://git.apache.org/hadoop.git
```

For check out to branch 2.6 use the below command.

```
git checkout branch-2.6
```

Following link will help you to create patch.

https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GitAndHadoop